# shorter way to merge, shuffle and take first n elements of a list

Tags: python, list, concatenation, unique, shuffle

I'm doing that (see code) and i'm thinking that there will be a shorter way

```
    fd_list = list(set(fd_list1 + fd_list2 + fd_list3))
    shuffle(fd_list)
    fd_list = fd_list[:10]
```

what i want to do is: concatenate three list's, shuffle them and take the first 10 elements. Alternativ i could merge the three list's and take randomly 10 elements?!Maybe?! I don't know how. By the way the result list have to be unique.

EDIT*: example 
`list1 = [ 1, 2, 3, 6], list2 = [], list3 = [4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, ,8]`

a result should maybe look like this...

```
result = [3, 4, 5, 1 ,8 ,2 ,7 ,6]
```

i think the "sample" solution would be the best. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If it's random, there's no way to guarantee that it will be unique.

Comment: What do you mean by "unique"? Instead of shuffle and [:10] try `sample`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
random.sample(set(fd_list1 + fd_list2 + fd_list3), 10)
```

Comment: Beat me to it.  Note that the result is *not* in random order, though, it's in "set hash order".  Also, depending on how the three lists are generated and/or used, if you make them sets in the first place, `random.sample(set1 | set2 | set3, 10)` might suffice.